# Given a characteristic function for a standard normal distribution, how does one find$ \operatorname{Var}(X^k)$?

Tags: probability

I learned how to compute $\Bbb E[X^k]$ for a a standard normal distribution using the characteristic function $e^{tX}$, where $X$ is a random variable.

How do I find $\operatorname{Var} (X^k)$ using the characteristic function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Note that $$\text{Var}(X^k) = \mathbb{E}[X^{2k}] - \left(\mathbb{E}[X^k]\right)^2.$$

Can you compute these two expectations?

Comment: Well, suppose k = 3. The rightmost RHS term vanishes. And the left RHS term should reduce to 15. So Var(X^3) = 15.